# Renaming files using regular expressions - Linux

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I have three files named

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I am trying to rename them to

```
mynewfile-1.txt
mynewfile-2.txt
mynewfile-3.txt
```

How would I go about this using regular expressions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this :

```
rename -n 's/^file/mynewfile-/' ./*.txt
```

or from comments :

```
rename -n 's/^file(\d+)/mynewfile-${1}-test/' ./*.txt
                   ___            ____
                    ^               ^
              capturing group       |
                               captured group
```

Drop `-n` switch when the output looks good to rename for real.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ rename
```

and you see `perlexpr`, then this seems to be the right tool.

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

For archlinux:

```
pacman -S perl-rename
```

---

For RedHat-family distros:

```
yum install prename
```

The 'prename' package is in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

---

For Gentoo:

```
emerge dev-perl/rename
```

---

For *BSD:

```
pkg install p5-File-Rename
```

---

For Mac users:

```
brew install rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

Or you can use perl CPAN:

```
cpan -i File::Rename
```

Old standalone version can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename)

---

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: If i wanted to instead turn them into mynewfile1-test.txt how would i do that?

Comment: `rename -n 's/^file(\d+)/mynewfile-${1}-test/' *.txt`

Comment: Super complete answer ! +1

Comment: That one is even more complete: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895