# renaming files using regular expression in bash

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regex to rename few files following this post

[Renaming files using regular expressions - Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267913/renaming-files-using-regular-expressions-linux)

There are my files -

```
abcd_some_random_alphanumeric_1.pdf
abcd_some_random_alphanumeric_2.pdf
abcd_some_random_alphanumeric_3.pdf
abcd_some_random_alphanumeric_4.pdf
abcd_some_random_alphanumeric_5.pdf
```

I would like to rename the files to

```
abcd_1.pdf
abcd_2.pdf 
abcd_3.pdf 
abcd_4.pdf 
abcd_5.pdf
```

I am trying the following

```
rename 's/abcd_.*_(/d+).pdf/abcd_${1}.pdf/' *.pdf
```

But I get lots of errors -

```
Unknown regexp modifier "/a" at (user-supplied code), near ""
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at (user-supplied code), near "{
#line 1
"
Unknown regexp modifier "/c" at (user-supplied code), near "{
#line 1
...........
"
```

However, I want the _1, _2, _3 etc in the end.. and I dont know how to capture data using a regular expression from the original string and put the captured group in the replace part.

Comment: There's a warning there, in bold letters: **"There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful."** Indeed, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html shows a completely different utility. Check the manpage/help text for yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off, and a single digit in regex is `\d`, with a backslash not forward slash.  Also the dot in the extension `.pdf` should be escaped.  Try this:

```
rename 's/abcd_.*_(\d+)\.pdf/abcd_$1.pdf/' *.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
rename -n 's/^(abcd).*(_[0-9]+\.pdf)$/$1$2/' *.pdf
```

- `$1$2` - the 1st and 2nd captured groups